# Unable to stop apache on Mac OSx Yosemite 10.10

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew

I have installed php56 with apache2.4 using homebrew. Everything is find except I am unable to stop apache or restart it completely.

This should stop apache: `sudo apachectl -k stop`

But when I grep the process list I see: `ps ax|grep httpd`

`7269   ??  Ss     0:00.17 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 7270   ??  S      0:00.02 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 7273   ??  S      0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND`

Even killing does not stops it: `sudo killall httpd`
which kills httpd but after a while it restarts: `ps ax|grep httpd`

`7684   ??  Rs     0:00.13 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 7686 s003  S+     0:00.00 grep httpd`

After a while:  `ps ax|grep httpd`

`7684   ??  Ss     0:00.15 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 7687   ??  S      0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
 7690 s003  S+     0:00.00 grep httpd`

In an ideal scenario :

start : `brew services start apache2`

stop : `brew services stop apache2`

The question is why httpd service is autostarted and is there is a fix for this bug ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that there is either a LaunchDaemon or LaunchAgent that has been set to KeepAlive.

Also, did you use `sudo brew services` when you loaded apache?  If so, regular `brew services` interact with just the user agents, not the system.

Comment: please add more detail about KeepAlive setting and if I can disable that

Comment: I don't use sudo with brew , I am not sure if that is required with `brew services` command

Comment: thanks for pointing I removed the httpd by launchctl `sudo launchctl remove org.apache.httpd`. After that stop and start working fine

Comment: When using `sudo` with `brew services`, the services are loaded systemwide, e.g.; when the system starts.  If you omit `sudo`, the services are loaded only to the user, e.g; when the user logs in. Therefore, you need to be cautious of the command you run.