# macOS Mojave - httpd process is running, but sudo apachectl stop results in httpd (no pid file) not running

Tags: macos, macos-mojave

Title pretty much covers it. I have an apache web server taking over localhost. When I visit http://127.0.0.1 I see a white page with "It works!" on it. Default apache stuff.

I take a look at running httpd processes, which shows multiple running

```
> ps -ef | grep httpd
    0 47867     1   0  8:24AM ??         0:00.18 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
   70 47871 47867   0  8:24AM ??         0:00.00 /usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
```

This is interferring with another service I want to use for localhost. So I try to kill the local apache only to get the "not running" response.

```
> sudo apachectl stop
httpd (no pid file) not running
```

So how do I stop the running apache process?

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50505408/unable-to-stop-apache-on-mac-osx-yosemite-10-10/50505792).  It looks like it depends on how you've installed Apache.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this error has many causes, but here's one I just encountered and the corresponding solution.

You can get this misleading error message if the apache process is owned by root and you execute the `apachectl` command as a different user.

If you have root access on the machine, you can do `sudo apachectl stop` and that should work.  I'm not aware of a way to stop it if you don't have root access.

Answer (score 0):

Try following command in you mac terminal:

**command1:** sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist

**command2:** sudo apachectl -k restart

Then try ***sudo apachectl start***